# Mysql selecting from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anybody tell me how to select data from two tables, without having to use join?

Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       t2.*
  FROM table1 t1, 
       table2 t2
```

###Clarification
I have these two tables, that have the same fields. IE: `table1` contains data from 2011 and `table2` contains data in 2012. I want to get them all.

###Further clarification:
The result set desired can be produced by:

```
(SELECT tr.full_name, tr.headlines, tr.content, tr.stamp, tr.person_key
 FROM tbl_transactions tr
          JOIN persons p ON p.person_key = tr.person_key
          JOIN teams t ON (pp.membership_id = t.id and pp.membership_type = 'teams')
 WHERE t.team_key = '')
UNION
(SELECT tr.full_name, tr.headlines, tr.content, tr.stamp, tr.person_key
 FROM tbl_transactions_bk_2012 tr
          JOIN persons p ON p.person_key = tr.person_key
          JOIN teams t ON (pp.membership_id = t.id and pp.membership_type = 'teams')
 WHERE t.team_key = ''
```

and the OP wishes to see if there are alternative ways to speed this up ("I tried to use `UNION` in between those queries. but query speed took 0.1887 secs. it's kinda slow.")

(@Jetoox: if this is not your intent, please edit your question and clarify).

Comment: Do you have a specific use case or are you just curious?

Comment: i have these two tables that has the same fields, example table1 contains data from 2011 and table2 contains data in 2012. I want to get them all.

Comment: is Union Can Work Here.If the Number of Columns are same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Selecting data from multiple tables all with same structure but different data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409705/mysql-selecting-data-from-multiple-tables-all-with-same-structure-but-differen)

Comment: both of these tables contains the same example person_key, and when i run the query. mysql say's unknown column person_key.

Comment: Are you *sure* each table contains a column named `person_key`?

Comment: yes @mathematical.coffee

Comment: @DawnUser: You cut out pertinent information in the question, possibly due to editing an older copy of it.  Mind what you are doing.

Comment: @OMGPonies there are tags to specify it is MySQL related... "without having to use join" is crucial from my point of view and now, you have cut that out.

Comment: @Jetoox: Can you post the relevant output of `show columns from table1;` and table2 to verify you have a column with that name? And the exact query you are running (edit your question with them)? "Unknown column xxx" usually means that that column doesn't exist in that table.

Comment: @DawnUser: I explained why I responded as I did to your suggested edit.  The tag/title detail is trivial compared to the question.

Comment: i created two queries for that and use php array_merge. so that's why i want to make it just one query. I tried to use UNION in between those queries. but query speed took 0.1887 secs. it's kinda slow.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just put the join condition in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

That is an inner join, though.

## UPDATE

Upon looking at your queries: In this particular case, there is no relation between `tbl_transactions` and `tbl_transactions_bk_2012` (i.e. joining these on person_key is meaningless because there is no relationship between the two tables in the way that (say) tbl_transactions and persons are related).

Then, you should use the `UNION` approach. Trying to join the first query to the second using either `JOIN` or `FROM xx, yy WHERE xx.id=yy.id` is meaningless and won't give you the results you need.

By the way, in the future, put your current query/attempt in your post - as you can see it will prevent you from getting answers that aren't appropriate for your question (as my first attempt was).

Comment: both of these tables contains the same example person_key, and when i run the query. mysql say's unknown column person_key.

Comment: Please post your *exact* query that you are using, and also the output of `show columns from table1 where Field='person_key'` and `show columns from table2 where Field='person_key'`. If your two tables are related by a *common* key `person_key`, use the `WHERE` condition. If your two tables are entirely unrelated, use the `UNION`.

Comment: (SELECT tr.full_name,tr.headlines,tr.content,tr.stamp,tr.person_key
  FROM tbl_transactions tr
  JOIN persons p ON p.person_key = tr.person_key
  JOIN teams t ON (pp.membership_id = t.id and pp.membership_type = 'teams')
  WHERE
  t.team_key = '')
UNION
(SELECT tr.full_name,tr.headlines,tr.content,tr.stamp,tr.person_key
  FROM tbl_transactions_bk_2012 tr
  JOIN persons p ON p.person_key = tr.person_key
  JOIN teams t ON (pp.membership_id = t.id and pp.membership_type = 'teams')
  WHERE
  t.team_key = '')

Comment: @Jetoox: in this particular case, since there is no relation between `tbl_transactions` and `tbl_transactions_bk_2012` (i.e. joining these on `person_key` is meaningless because there is no relationship between the two tables in the way that (say) `tbl_transactions` and `persons` are related), you should use the `UNION` approach - trying to join the first query to the second using either `JOIN` or `FROM xx, yy WHERE xx.id=yy.id` is meaningless and won't give you the results you need.

Answer (score 12):

You want [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
(SELECT tr.full_name, tr.headlines, tr.content, tr.stamp, tr.person_key
 FROM tbl_transactions tr
          JOIN persons p ON p.person_key = tr.person_key
          JOIN teams t ON (pp.membership_id = t.id and pp.membership_type = 'teams')
 WHERE t.team_key = '')
UNION
(SELECT tr.full_name, tr.headlines, tr.content, tr.stamp, tr.person_key
 FROM tbl_transactions_bk_2012 tr
          JOIN persons p ON p.person_key = tr.person_key
          JOIN teams t ON (pp.membership_id = t.id and pp.membership_type = 'teams')
 WHERE t.team_key = ''
```

Comment: Answer from another question about Union: http://stackoverflow.com/a/409720/1218980

Comment: both of these tables contains the same example person_key, and when i run the query. mysql say's unknown column person_key.

Answer (score 4):

```
select t1.*, t2.* from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.fkey = t2.pkey
```

Comment: both of these tables contains the same example person_key, and when i run the query. mysql say's unknown column person_key.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.* , t2.*
from t1, t2 where t1.id=t2.id;
```

Comment: both of these tables contains the same example person_key, and when i run the query. mysql say's unknown column person_key.

Answer (score 0):

While using the UNION query, you may also want to add indexes to any columns that you are using to join and filter which will improve performance