# Mysql query to get desired result

Tags: mysql, select, join

I have been working with SQL joins and kinda stuck with following scenario:

Table 1: PK(ID, GRADE)

### | ID | Grade | Student_Count |

|   1    |     10th      |               20                  |
|   1    |     9th        |               20                  |
|   2    |     10th      |               20                  |
|   2    |       9th      |               20                  |

Table 2:PK(ID, Grade, Visited_Date)

### | ID | Grade | Visited | Visit_Date |

|   1   |    10th     |      Yes       |  25-Dec-2015  | 
|   1   |    10th     |       No        |  26-Dec-2015  | 
|   1   |     9th      |      Yes       |  28-Dec-2015  | 
|   1   |     9th      |       No        |  29-Dec-2015  | 
|   2   |    10th     |      Yes       |  27-Dec-2015  | 
|   2   |     9th      |       No        |  30-Dec-2015  |

What i need is a **SELECT** query which returns data from both the tables for a given ID in such a way that output rows should match the data of the Table 2 (no all possible combinations like cross/dot product) along with non-common columns from Table 1. 
 
For example for ID "1" the output should be:

### | ID | Grade | Student_Count | Visited | Visit_date |

|   1   |     10th     |               20                  |      Yes      |  25-Dec-2015  |

|   1   |     10th     |               20                  |       No       |  26-Dec-2015  |

|   1   |      9th      |               20                  |      Yes      |  28-Dec-2015  |

|   1   |      9th      |               20                  |       No       |  29-Dec-2015  |

**Note**: There is no foreign key association between both the tables.

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460435/mysql-selecting-from-two-tables

Comment: Shouldn't the desired result row with date "29-Dec-2015" be "9th" grade?

Comment: @Prashantsoni Didn't understand last row of output for ID "1" - |   1   |     10th     |               20                  |       No       |  29-Dec-2015  |; I think grade should be 9 instead of 10 or I am getting it incorrect.

Comment: I've removed the SQL-Server tag as this is a different product.  SQL Server answers won't always work with MySQL.

Comment: @NayanWadekar: You got it right. It was a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to JOIN both tables on the `id` and  `grade` fields.

```
SELECT b.ID, b.Grade, a.Student_Count, b.Visited, b.Visit_date
FROM table2 b 
INNER JOIN table1 a 
ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.Grade = b.Grade
ORDER BY a.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, this works just fine. I missed Join on Grade in my original query