# Simple SELECT statement query with error

Tags: sql, postgresql

It is a simple SELECT statement where i pick data from two tables

```
SELECT 
    bookingid, customerid, flightid, numseats, 
    passengerid, firstname, surname, passportno,  
    nationality, dobdate
FROM 
    flightbooking, passenger;
```

I get an error:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
>   LINE 9: SELECT bookingid, customerid, flightid, numseats, passengeri...
>          ^

I am using PG Admin 4.

Comment: No join condition?!?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! **Easier to write (without errors)**, easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: However, your syntax is valid. (But will probably not return what you want.)

Comment: Yes, i need a inner join, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two tables so you should use `inner join`
please check this [Mysql SELECTIONG FROM TWO TABLES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460435/mysql-selecting-from-two-tables)

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot, start by changing your query from this:

```
SELECT bookingid
, customerid
, flightid
, numseats
, passengerid
, firstname
, surname
, passportno
, nationality
, dobdate

FROM flightbooking, passenger;
```

to this:

```
SELECT 1 bookingid
/*
, customerid
, flightid
, numseats
, passengerid
, firstname
, surname
, passportno
, nationality
, dobdate
*/

FROM flightbooking join passenger on 1 =2;
```

If it runs successfully, change `select 1 bookingid` to `select bookingid`.  If that runs successfully, uncomment 1 field at a time until you get an error.  The last field you uncomment would be the cause.