# Mysql union from multiple database tables

Tags: php, mysql, union

I have a group of databases which have a table with **same schema**. So, i am doing a `UNION` on this table to show the records from all databases, which works nice.

But, now i have to detect which row belongs to which database/table, as i need to modify that particular record. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409705/mysql-selecting-data-from-multiple-tables-all-with-same-structure-but-differen) link on getting the `UNION`, but am unable to find the logic which determines row<->table relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
(SELECT *, 'db1' as DB_NAME from db1..table1)
union
(SELECT *, 'db2' as DB_NAME from db2..table1)
union
(SELECT *, 'db3' as DB_NAME from db3..table1)
...
```

Answer (score 7):

Not really sure what's allowed in your case, my suggestion is to have an additional field with a number in it:

```
select field1, field2, 1 as db from db1.tb
UNION
select field1, field2, 2 as db from db2.tb1
UNION
select field1, field2, 3 as db from db1.tb4
UNION
```

with said field you can identify the source of each record.

Comment: I am typing on my cellphone. By the time I finished, another poster beat ne to it. U am glad you got the corrwct answer you sought.

Answer (score 1):

You could just add a column with database name in the queries

```
(SELECT *,'db1' as db from db1..us_music where `genre` = 'punk')
UNION
(SELECT *,'db2' as db from db2..us_music where `genre` = 'punk')
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a completely separate database, Oracle, SQL Server or the data resides on a separate server where they can't be UNIONed directly (this happens to us with an (*PeopleSoft/Oracle*) ERP database and an engineering DB (*MySQL*) for test results). You can do the query on one of the DBs, keep the result set in memory and construct a query like this:

```
SELECT '' AS SN, 'PRD0547016' AS Prdn_ID UNION
SELECT '' AS SN, 'PRD0547435' AS Prdn_ID UNION
SELECT sn, pid AS Prdn_ID
    FROM build left join product on prod_idx=product.idx WHERE sn='23456-1' 
       AND PID not in ('dgh')
        ORDER BY Prdn_ID;
```

In this particular case, I end up with:

```
'23456-1', 'pid 2'
'23456-1', 'pid 3'
'', 'PRD0547016'
'', 'PRD0547435'
```

I had wanted to SELECT INTO, yada, yada..., but transferring files from server to server, creating temporary tables, etcetera; was too much programming and I'll bet this is the computationally fastest solution too.

Answer (score 0):

Try DATABASE() function

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_database

Comment: it will only tell me which database am i currently connected to. But, the result will get results from multiple databases. I am looking to find to which database / table does the current result belong.