# Row wise merge two different table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two different tables.One is `file` and another one is `image`. If uploaded content is image, then content details are stored in image table. Remaining(like doc,pdf etc) things are stored in file table. Both are identified by `folder_id`.

Now I want to list both files and images according to given folder_id.

Exapmle:

**image table**

```
image_id   description     img_orig        img_sm       folder_id
   1         Image one   img_one.png     img_one.png        1
   2         Image_two   img_two.png     img_two.png        1
   3         Image_three img_three.png   img_three.png      2
```

**File Table**

```
file_id       description       file_name    file_size   folder_id  file_type
    1          file_one          one.txt       11KB            1      text/plain
    2          file_two          two.html       2KB            1      text/html
```

**Expected output table is**

```
  1         Image one   img_one.png     img_one.png         1      image
  2         Image_two   img_two.png     img_two.png         1      image
  1         file_one    one.txt          11KB               1      text/plain
  2         file_two    two.html         2KB                1      text/html
```

I have tried `UNION ALL`  concept in MYSQL. 
My snippet is

```
SELECT image_id as id,description,img_orig as name, img_sm as sm_size,folder_id,CONCAT('image','') as type 
UNION ALL
SELECT folder_id as id,description,file_name as name, file_size as sm_size,folder_id,file_type as type 
WHERE folder_id=1
```

It is working fine. But my question is have any another solution in this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Selecting data from multiple tables all with same structure but different data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409705/mysql-selecting-data-from-multiple-tables-all-with-same-structure-but-differen)

Comment: I did n't get any point from your link. Already I used UNOIN ALL concept here.

Comment: Can you explain more..

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple JOIN. You can pull any columns from any table. Just make sure to prefix the columns with table name or an alias as below.

```
Select I.image_id, I.description as img_desc, 
F.description as file_desc, F.folder_id
From image I, file F
where I.folder_id = F.folder_id
```

Comment: I have tried your snippet. But only you are select values from image table. I want to fetch values from file table also

Comment: Basically I think JOIN is used for combine columns of tables

Comment: @AjithaMs In that case, I can't think of anything else other than UNION.