# Query Multiple table with same structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a few tables with the same structure built and wanted to query them at once using PHP MYSQL.
The challenging part that I face was to query x tables where I do not know how many of them there. (Assuming user will select the tables on UI perspective). The reason of this is to output them into a csv format.

For example:-

```
Date, xTable, yTable, zTable, ....
==============================b
bla      1        2      3
bla      4        3      5
...
...
```

How can I modify below query to cater for above needs? (The query needs to be flexible enough  to query multi table).

> SELECT created_dt,
>   xTable FROM needToQueryMultiTable WHERE created_dt BETWEEN ? AND ?

Comment: are you querying 1 column from each table?

Comment: 2 columns as of now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409705/mysql-selecting-data-from-multiple-tables-all-with-same-structure-but-differen?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view of all possible tables:

```
create v_tables as
    select 'table1' as which, t.*
    from table1 t
    union all
    select 'table2' as which, t.*
    from table2 t
    . . .;
```

Then, you can select from the view.

In MySQL this is not particularly efficient, because all the tables will still need to be read.  However, for smaller tables this could be a reasonable solution.

You should ask yourself why you have identically structured tables in the databases.  In general, these should be combined into a single table.  For performance, you can partition the table.

Comment: Will that be a case that I wouldn't able to recognise the columns from which table

Comment: @EricT . . . I don't understand your comment.  You say all the tables have the same structure so I assume that means they have the same column names.

Comment: when I do a union all they will merge up all the data where I wouldn't able to know the data is from which table. Having said the csv format needs to recognize data by table basis.

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff, is it possible for you to put up some looping codes here. So that the rest can refer if they face the same problem. Thank you.